# Is there a way to make SQL Management Studio never generate USE [database-name] in scripts?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to turn this 'feature' off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Awesome, I just found it:

`Tools -> Options -> Sql Server Object Explorer -> General Scripting Options`

`Script USE <database> -> False`

Answer (score 2):

Tools -> Options -> Sql Server Object Explorer -> Scripting -> **Script USE <database>** (under the *General scripting options* heading).

That's in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, I'm told it's there in 2005, too.